# CPU FSB and MotherBoard FSB

Tags: cpu, motherboard, speed, fsb

I have a Intel processor (E6300 @1.86 GHZ) it's FSB is 1066 MHZ (as mentioned [over here](http://ark.intel.com/products/27248/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E6300-%282M-Cache-1_86-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB%29?wapkw=%28e6300%29)).

Now If I install a new compatible motherboard having a DDR3 RAM (4GB) with 1333 MHz then will it be okay? I mean will that give me complete 1333 MHz or only 1066 MHz (because the processor has 1066 MHz FSB), also will it be alright to use such sort of config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory will downclock to 1066MHz to sync with the FSB.

Comment: Will that be a problem. i.e. will it cause a hardware failure to any component?

Comment: No, it won't. @Gaurav